# Subqueries as the input to the MS Jet CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, subquery, ms-access-2007, create-table

I am trying to write a CREATE TABLE sql that pulls its columns and data from a subquery (basic Select with an Aggregate MAX function).  I've tested the subquery by itself and it works fine, but once i put it into the CREATE TABLE MapData AS ...  it errors out.  Any advice?  or is this not even possible in MS Access?

Thanks,
Stacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL's [CREATE TABLE Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177893%28v=office.12%29.aspx) doesn't provide what I think you're looking for.  Consider [SELECT…INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208934%28v=office.12%29.aspx) instead.

A very simple example ...

```
SELECT
    fld1,
    fld2,
    etc
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTableOrQuery;
```

If you run into trouble with that approach, show us the query from which you want to create a table.  Meanwhile, here's another example which you may find useful ...

```
SELECT
    sub.FacNo,
    sub.QualRating AS Qrate,
    sub.MaxOfSqFeet AS sqFeet
INTO MapData
FROM
    (
        SELECT FACNO, QualRating, MAX(SqFeet) AS MaxOfSqFeet
        FROM April_2_ISR_report
        GROUP BY FACNO, QualRating
    ) AS sub;
```

Comment: HansUp,
Does the INTO table need to pre-exist, or will the sql create it?

Comment: The statement will create the table.  If a table by the same name already exists, I *think* it will throw an error.  But you should check me out on that point.

Comment: I HATE doing this -feel i should work it out on my own and learn, but i've gone round and round with this for over an hour.  I tried it, table does NOT pre-exist and it err'd on the FROM clause.  Below is my sql:

Comment: SELECT FacNo, Qrate, sqFeet
INTO MapData 
FROM (SELECT FACNO, QualRating, MAX(SqFeet) FROM April_2_ISR_report GROUP BY FACNO, QualRating;);

Comment: Ok, that worked...BUT, apparently you can't use an aliased column from the subquery to populate the new table.  This is the sql that worked:

Comment: SELECT FacNo, QualRating, sqFeet
INTO MapData 
FROM (SELECT FACNO, QualRating, MAX(SqFeet) FROM April_2_ISR_report GROUP BY FACNO, QualRating);

Comment: HA!  Yes, I'll do that.  Thanks again HansUp!

Comment: ok, i'm brand new to this board, where do i go to give you an Upvote?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I was typing instructions when you found it.  BTW, I was joking about the birthday present.  :-)

Comment: good sense of humor, always nice.  Thanks again and have a good day!